# Where is 7-Zip's compression source code?

Tags: compression, 7zip

I need the source code for the compression used in [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip). Does anyone have a link?

Comment: I don't think the last tag 'plzsendtehcodez' is appropriate. Consider removing it and/or substituting it with LZMA if that is really what you are interested in.

Comment: How to contribute to those C++ files? is there an official portal to send in pull requests?

Comment: Here's a mirror of the releases as a gift repo. https://github.com/kornelski/7z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full source code for 7-Zip is available for download on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files). Each release has the source code in a 7-Zip archive, such as "7z1900-src.7z" for version 19.00.

Comment: They simply re-defined "open source".

Comment: Ah yes.

If 7-Zip were one of the projects that cost money but are open source, this would be classified as a paywall.

Answer (score 5):

7-Zip is open source, just go their website and download it - <http://7zip.org>.

Comment: see files C/LzmaEnc.c and C/LzmaDec.c

Comment: I find it quite funny that you _need_ 7-Zip in order to view its source code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [official SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).

Answer (score 1):

Google finds it. Just download the [SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).